# Xsim shortsolution appear after each exercise

Tags: xsim

I am trying to have a document with some exercise and solution.
I know there is many packages to do that, and I chose `xsim` because it fits to many of my criteria.

Now, I would like to had a short solution after each exercise.
I found one example given with the documentation of the package that had such `shortsolution` environment.
But I do not know how to make them appear after each exercise.

I tried (without luck) to used a syntax close to the environment `solution` which can appear after each exercise using the comment `\xsimsetup{solution/print = true}`.

So here is my MWE:

```
% http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/23968/
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

% new property:
\DeclareExerciseProperty{shortsolution}

% new environment:
\NewDocumentEnvironment{shortsolution}{+b}
  {%
    \edef\ExerciseType{\csname g_xsim_exercise_type_tl\endcsname}%
    \edef\ExerciseID{\csname g_xsim_exercise_id_tl\endcsname}%
    \SetExerciseProperty{shortsolution}{#1}%
  }
  {}

% we'll use a description list for the list of short solutions:
\newcommand\printshortsolutions{%
  \begin{description}
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
      \GetExercisePropertyT{shortsolution}
        {\item[Short Solution ##3]####1}%
    }%
  \end{description}
}

\xsimsetup{ % This something I added and not working !
   shortsolution/print = true,
}

\begin{document}

\section{Problems}
% set shortsolution through option:
\begin{exercise}[subtitle=Pythagoras]
  This is the first problem.
\end{exercise}
\begin{shortsolution}
  This is a shortsolution to the first problem.
\end{shortsolution}
\begin{solution}
  This is the solution to the first problem.
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}[subtitle=Another Problem]
  This is the second problem.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  This is the solution to the second problem.
\end{solution}

% set shortsolution with custom command:
\begin{exercise}[subtitle=Yet Another Problem]
  This is the third problem.
\end{exercise}
\begin{shortsolution}
  This is a shortsolution to the third problem.
\end{shortsolution}
\begin{solution}
  This is the solution to the third problem.
\end{solution}

\section{Shortsolutions}
\printshortsolutions

\section{Solutions}
\printsolutions[headings=false]

\end{document}
```

And as a bonus question, how to change the layout of the `shortsolution` environment displayed ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly an additional `#1` should do in the environment definition, before or after `\SetExerciseProperty{shortsolution}{#1}`.

Comment: @cgnieder, Yes you understood well. I think the difficulty here is to have this printing being optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to typeset the shortsolution where the environment `shortsolution` is placed in the document just place another `#1` in the definition, see the lines marked with `<<<<`

   ```
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{shortsolution}{+b}
      {%
        \edef\ExerciseType{\csname g_xsim_exercise_type_tl\endcsname}%
        \edef\ExerciseID{\csname g_xsim_exercise_id_tl\endcsname}%
        \SetExerciseProperty{shortsolution}{#1}%
        before% <<<<
        #1%     <<<<
        after%  <<<<
      }
      {}
   ```
2. How you change the layout here is the same as everywhere else: `\textbf{#1}` would print it in bold, `\textcolor{red}{#1}` makes it red (given yuo load the `xcolor` package in the preamble), etc. The next example would place it in a `tcolorbox`:

   ```
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{shortsolution}{+b}
      {%
        \edef\ExerciseType{\csname g_xsim_exercise_type_tl\endcsname}%
        \edef\ExerciseID{\csname g_xsim_exercise_id_tl\endcsname}%
        \SetExerciseProperty{shortsolution}{#1}%
        \begin{tcolorbox}
          #1
        \end{tcolorbox}
      }
      {}
   ```

   [image]
3. Making this optional can be done by a simple switch

   ```
    \newif\ifshortsolprint
   ```

   and

   ```
    \ifshortsolprint
    \begin{tcolorbox}
      #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \fi
   ```

   which can be controlled via `\shortsolprinttrue` and `\newif\shortsolprintfalse` anywhere after the `\newif\ifshortsolprint`.

   Of course a key for `\xsimsetup` could also be defined but would require expl3:

   ```
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \bool_new:N \l_xsim_shortsolution_bool

    \keys_define:nn {xsim}
      { shortsolution/print .bool_set:N = \l_xsim_shortsolution_bool }

    % new environment:
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{shortsolution}{+b}
      {
        \tl_set:NV \ExerciseType \g_xsim_exercise_type_tl
        \tl_set:NV \ExerciseID \g_xsim_exercise_id_tl
        \SetExerciseProperty {shortsolution} {#1}
        \bool_if:NT \l_xsim_shortsolution_bool
          { \begin{tcolorbox} #1 \end{tcolorbox} }
      }
      {}
    \ExplSyntaxOff
   ```

   This could now be controlled with

   ```
    \xsimsetup{ shortsolution/print = true }
   ```